# How to convert a json tree data into dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, tree

I have a json data which can be represented as the tree structure with each node has four attributes: `name`,`id`,`child`,`parentid(pid)` (for leaf node it has only three attributes: `id`,`pid`,`name`).

```
{'child': [{'id': '','child':[{'id': '','child':['name':'','id':'','pid':''], 'name': '', 'pid':''}], 'name': '', 'pid': ''}],'name':'','pid':'','id':''}
```

I want to convert it to a dataframe with three columns like:

```
    id, pid, name
1   .., ..., ....
2   .., ..., ....
```

With the data from all layers in three attributes `(id,pid,name)`

I have tried `pandas.read_json` with the default parameters but it seems that it cannot iterate the whole layers and the output is just like:

```
    id, pid, name, child
1   .., ..., ...., {'id':'','pid': '','name': '', 'child':[{...}]}
2   .., ..., ...., {'id':'','pid': '','name': '', 'child':[{...}]}
```

I am wondering whether there are some easy methods to solve this problem with or without `pandas`.

Comment: Try using the [`json_normalize()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html?highlight=json_normalize#pandas.io.json.json_normalize) function or, depending on the complexity of your data, have a look at the `flatten` [library](https://github.com/amirziai/flatten) ([blog post](https://medium.com/@amirziai/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10)).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems that  `json_normalize()` not work for me (maybe I set the wrong parameter) and `flatten` just returns too many columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a recursion to fulfill it and I have proved that it works on my data.

```
import json
import pandas as pd


def test_iterate(df):
    global total_data
    total_data = total_data.append(df[['id','pid','name']])
    try:
        df['child'].apply(lambda x:test_iterate(pd.DataFrame(x)))
    except Exception as inst:
        print(inst)
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    total_data = pd.DataFrame()
    loaddata = json.load(open('test.json'))
    df = pd.DataFrame(loaddata)
    test_iterate(df)
    total_data.to_csv('test.csv',index=None)
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and was able to get the output using your answer. For every children data frame if I want to add a column to have it's parentID, how do I do it? Kindly help